# Vue class components dynamically add component depending on answer from backend

Tags: vue.js, dynamically-generated, vue-class-components

So from the backend I get a array of objects that look kind of like this

```
ItemsToAdd 
 {
  Page: MemberPage
  Feature: Search
  Text: "Something to explain said feature"
 }
```

So i match these values to enums in the frontend and then on for example the memberpage i do this check

```
private get itemsForPageFeatures(): ItemsToAdd[] {
  return this.items.filter(
    (f) =>
      f.page== Pages.MemberPage &&
      f.feature != null
  );
}
```

What we get from the backend will change a lot over time and is only the same for weeks at most. So I would like to avoid to have to add the components in the template as it will become dead code fast and will become a huge thing to have to just go around and delete dead code. So preferably i would like to add it using a function and then for example for the search feature i would have a ref on the parent like

```
<SearchBox :ref="Features.Search" />
```

and in code just add elements where the `ItemsToAdd` objects `Feature` property match the ref

is this possible in Vue? things like `appendChild` and so on doesn't work in Vue but that is the closest thing i can think of to kind of what I want. This function would basically just loop through the `itemsForPageFeatures` and add the features belonging to the page it is run on.

For another example how the template looks

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
  <div
    class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between flex-wrap align-items-center"
  >
    <div class="d-align-self-end">
      <SearchBox :ref="Features.Search" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <MessagesFilter
    :ref="Features.MessagesFilter"
  />

  <DataChart
    :ref="Features.DataChart"
  />
```

So say we got an answer from backend where it contains an `object` that has a feature property `DataChart` and another one with `Search` so now i would want components to be added under the DataChart component and the SearchBox component but not the `messagesFilter` one as we didnt get that from the backend. But then next week we change in backend so we no longer want to display the Search feature component under searchbox. so we only get the object with `DataChart` so then it should only render the `DataChart` one. So the solution would have to work without having to make changes to the frontend everytime we change what we want to display as the backend will only be database configs that dont require releases.

Closest i can come up with is this function that does not work for Vue as appendChild doesnt work there but to help with kind of what i imagine. So the component to be generated is known and will always be the same type of component. It is where it is to be placed that is the dynamic part.

```
private showTextBoxes() {
  this.itemsForPageFeatures.forEach((element) => {
    let el = this.$createElement(NewMinorFeatureTextBox, {
      props: {
        item: element,
      },
    });

    var ref = `${element.feature}`

    this.$refs.ref.appendChild(el);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic components for it. use it like this:

```
<component v-for="item in itemsForPageFeatures" :is="getComponent(item.Feature)" :key="item.Feature"/>
```

also inside your script:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          Page: "MemberPage",
          Feature: "Search",
          Text: "Something to explain said feature"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    itemsForPageFeatures() {
      return this.items.filter(
        f =>
          f.Page === "MemberPage" &&
          f.Feature != null
      );
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getComponent(feature) {
      switch (feature) {
        case "Search":
          return "search-box";
        default:
          return "";
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made some edits to my question to make the situation more clear. So i need the dynamic components to be put into different places in the template without knowing beforehand, so just going by for this example the :ref attribute and comparing it to the answer from backend.

Comment: You have to use dynamic components in vue as I provided the example. Using refs in this situation is not best practice.

Comment: the issue is that the component itself is always the same and does not need to be dynamic but it is the placement of the component that can be in a lot of different places that i would like to be dynamic and only be put where the properties tell it to be instead of having to spread out a lot of mostly dead components in the DOM

Comment: Your approach to the concept is incorrect. Vue can work as a SPA which fetchs data amd renders it in order to reduce dead components. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA